# Dynamic series for columrange (highcharts)

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to generate a dynamic series for `columnrange` in highcharts. Here is my sample generated string for the series

```
var x = [{"name": "series1", "data": [{"x": 0, "low": "08/10/2017 10:32:21", "high": "08/12/2017 10:32:21"}, {"x": 1, "low": "08/10/2017 10:32:21", "high": "08/17/2017 10:32:21"}]},{"name": "series2", "data": [{"x": 0, "low": "08/13/2017 15:32:21", "high": "08/20/2017 19:32:21"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn string representation of dates into timestamps. You can use `Date.parse()` function for this purpose.

API Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sdcsxrLv/